# How calculate mouth smile probability?

Tags: android

how can I implement smile probability method like Google face detection API?
now I have the three points of the mouth

this is the probability using Google API

```
for (int index = 0; index < faces.size(); ++index) {
            Face face = faces.valueAt(index);
            double x = face.getIsSmilingProbability();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a field variable:

> private static final double SMILE_PROB = 0.4;

Get a boolean value in your loop then work on it:

> boolean smiling = face.getIsSmilingProbability() > SMILING_PROB;